# MySQL insert into table foreign key column conditional insert i.e. exist or doesn't exist

Tags: mysql

Here are two tables:

Table 1:

```
CustomerId  | CustomerName
```

Table 2:

```
OrderId  | OrderNo  | CustomerId
```

Now I want to insert record into table 2 by using single query i.e.

```
Insert Into Table2 (OrderId,OrderNo,CustomerId) values (1,2456,( if select CustomerId from Customer where CustomerName = 'abc' is non-zero return id else insert into customer (CustomerId,CustomerName) values (1,'abc') return newly added customerid)
```

Note:  Ids are auto-generated and can be ignored, it's just from understanding perspective.

In short, I need to insert record into table2 and value for `customerid` may exist or may not exist, I need to handle this situation.

Comment: Din get u buddy..Could u please elaborate..

Comment: CustomerId will always be generated whenever their is any customerName inserted in the table, with this i dont think that their is any point saying that id do not exist for a particular customer. and according to humor insertion in table  1 is before than table 2 right.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* first execute first query, */
$q1=mysql_query($sql1);  /* for first table */
$foreign_id=mysql_insert_id(); /* fetch last id from first table*/
$q2=mysql_query($sql2)  /* insert into second table use $foreign_id as foreign key */
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be possible in MySQL using a single statement. However the following should work:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1 (CustomerName) VALUES ('abc');
INSERT INTO Table2 (OrderId,OrderNo,CustomerId) 
    VALUES (1,2456,(SELECT CustomerId FROM Table1 WHERE CustomerName='abc'));
```

Comment: Objective here is to do above mentioned in a more optimized manner. I don't think it's a good way to try to insert every time. I should try to insert only if select operation is failed.